# How to declare public properties implicitly in Angular?

Tags: angular, constructor, properties

Coming fom C#, I found the following syntax weird. At first. Then, I totally loved it because it's so much compact. No need to declare a back-field nor to assign the value in the constructor. In fact, the constructor of Angular is so light-weight it's almost anorectic.

```
constructor(private hazaa: number) { }
someMethod() { console.log(this.hazaa); }
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the same kind of syntax but for declaring publicly accessible properties. Today, I'm using the following approach for my DTOs.

```
export class BigInfoChunk{
  constructor(someValue: number, anotherValue: number, ...){
      this.infoA = someValue;
      this.InfoB = anotherValue;
      ...
    }
    infoA = 0;
    infoB = 1;
    ...
}
```

It'd be awesomely convenient to be able to go like this.

```
export class BigInfoChunk{
  constructor(public infoA: number, public infoB: number, ...){ }
}
```

I have tried that and noticed that, regrettably, it's not working. What is the correct syntax to achieve the automagical propertization but with the additional feature of having them publicly accessible?

Or is it so that it's not possible at all? In such case, I'd love to understand the reason or rationale behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aproach is absolutly correct. May your test is wrong?

You could also set default (and readonly) values like that:

```js
export class BigInfoChunk{
  constructor(
    public infoA: number = 0,
    public readonly infoB: number = 1,
    /*...*/
  ){ }
}
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes, mate. This is **precisely** what I tested and it didn't fly. (Or, rather, this is precisely what I **thought** I tested, haha.) Be back in a jiffy.

Comment: Confirming, it's compiling and seems to work. I think what I got stuck on is that I usually go with nullable properties and then protect against null like this: *constructor(public x?:number){this.x=x||-1;}* and when I added default value, it didn't fly with the question mark: *constructor(public x?:number=-1){}*. The rest is my confusion, hehe.

Comment: Don't know you know it already, but: The questionmark is an indicator for an optional argument. If you provide a default value with `infoA = 0`, the property is implicitly optional.
Without a default value and with a questionmark the parameter won't be `null` it will be `undefined` wich resolves to `false`.
You could use this behavior for a little trick. Skipping arguments. For Example: `new BigInfoChunk(undefined, 3)`. The first argument will take the default value ;)

Comment: One additional note: This behavior is not limited to Angular. It is a TypeScript feature. You could use TypeScript independant of Angular. Even on server side with node.js.

Comment: I knew "sort of" what the question mark does (in C# it's nullable type alteration so it's kind of similar if yet not fully). So your hint was actually spot on. Thanks for that. As we're discussing linguistic specifics, I have a follow-up to ask. Would you go with either of the following syntaxes or is one of them preferred due to technicals? (a) *constructor(public x=1){}* or (b) *constructor(public x:number=1){}*. I'm all for (a) because it's implictly typed, hence shorter. But I don't want to get into situation where everything is *any* just because it happens to compile.

Comment: Personally i use (b). I even set up the tslint to force my coworkers to use this. It is just my opinion and taste but i prefer consistency above implicity. AND if someone removes the default value in future, the type will be lost.

Comment: I am using WebStorm. But this should be IDE independent. Just set `"no-inferrable-types": false,` in your `tslint.json` file.